# Why does imported Type Library function differ from original source?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to use a third party library with a COM interface.
A C++ sample application is provided, which uses a function declared as:

```
HRESULT __stdcall IMyInterface::DoSomething (BSTR id, long State)
```

After importing the Type Library, the resulting Delphi code is:

```
procedure DoSomething (const id: WideString; State: Integer); safecall;
```

In the C++ sample application, the result (HRESULT) is used to determine if the function was executed properly.
Why does Delphi convert this declaration into a procedure so that I cannot get a result back?
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Sometimes I found that the Delphi generated tlb is wrong. I end up  editing the generated tlb file manually. Try changing the procedure into function and see if it works.

Comment: You don't need to examine it, Delphi throws an exception when the high-bit of the result is set, this is why the procedure is declared 'safecall'. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96042/whats-safecall) and answers to it.

Comment: On second thought, try running tlibimp from command prompt with -Pt- option (-Pt- Map HRESULT to safecall on all interfaces (-T)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `safecall` calling convention is simply a transformation of an `HResult` return type. If the function returns non-success (something other than `S_OK` or `S_False`, generally), it's wrapped into an exception and thrown (or turned into an `reSafeCallError` run-time error, if SysUtils hasn't been used anywhere). Check out `System._CheckAutoResult` for details.

Likewise, if you're implementing a safecall function, any exception is caught and translated into an `HResult` value (`E_Unexpected`, unless `TObject.SafeCallException` is overridden to return something else). See `System._HandleAutoException` for how that works.

You're welcome to turn the procedure back into a function returning `HResult` if you want. The calling convention in that case should be `stdcall`. Using your example:

```
function DoSomething(const id: WideString; State: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
```