# Passing strings in / out of Delphi COM Server

Tags: delphi, com, bstr

I've tried several variations of the code below with returning HRESULT (which is the preferable COM standard) or returning BSTR. I've tried other datatypes as well. I usually get a "missing implementation of interface method" compile error, but when I used a return type of WideString, there was a runtime  AccessViolationException on the `result:=RetVal;` instruction.

I'm using C# on the client side:

`var msg = delphi.GetMessage("My Message");`

Here is mi RIDL:

`HRESULT _stdcall GetMessage([in] BSTR msg, [out, retval] BSTR* RetVal);`

Here is my implementation:

```
function TDelphiCom.GetMessage(msg:WideString; out RetVal:WideString):HRESULT;
var
  tempString: string;
begin
  tempString:=msg;
  RetVal:=WideString(tempString);
end;
```

What is the correct way to pass strings in/out of a Delphi COM server?

Comment: What's wrong with the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RIDL declaration is correct.

You did not show the C# declaration of the method, so we can't see if you are marshaling parameters correctly or not.

On the Delphi side, your implementation is missing the `stdcall` calling convention (to match the RIDL declaration), as well as exception handling so you can return a proper `HRESULT` on failures:

```
function TDelphiCom.GetMessage(msg: WideString; out RetVal: WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  tempString: string;
begin
  try
    tempString := string(msg);
    RetVal := WideString(tempString);
    Result := S_OK;
  except
    // do something...
    Result := DISP_E_EXCEPTION;
  end;
end;
```

Though, you really should use the [`safecall` calling convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96042/whats-safecall) instead and let it deal with the error handling for you:

```
function TDelphiCom.GetMessage(msg: WideString): WideString; safecall;
var
  tempString: string;
begin
  tempString := string(msg);
  Result := WideString(tempString);
end;
```

Comment: The C# client code is near the top of the question - just one line.

Comment: @KevinS.Miller on the C# side, I was referring to the **declaration** of the method, not the **invokation** of it. We can't see how you declared it to know whether it is marshaling parameters correctly or not.

Comment: We don't know whether or not the stdcall was missing because the declaration wasn't shown, only the implementation. Always a problem when user presents partial code.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question about the C# declaration. The Delphi code produces a COM server, and the C# instantiates the COM server object and invokes GetMessage method (declared in the RIDL, and implemented in Delphi) of that server. Both the RIDL and the Delphi specify stdcall.

Comment: You are correct that the Delphi code above does not explicitly show the stdcall because it is declared in the function prototype and that is the implementation. I regret the omission.

Comment: I'm changing the accepted answer to this. At first, it would not compile, but I found that I had to enable SafeCall at Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Type Library > Tools > Options > Language > Delphi Options > Type Library.